# Normal maps not baking correctly due to correct cage setup?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, normals, texture-baking

Using the select to active technique, and when baking from high poly to low poly which is UV unwrapped via automatic unwrap, many smooth planes are made on the bake sheet, is this due to the image being too low res as the texture is 3k.

[image]

Comment: This might be because your "max ray distance" is too small so the rays cannot reach the high-poly model. try increasing it a bit and see if it makes it better

Comment: Also, increase the *Extrusion* value which creates a cage so the rays cannot hit another leg.